# pkftk.jar executable with bash script pdftk current directory

Tags: bash, java, bash-scripting, ubuntu-16.04, pdftk

In ubuntu-16.04 the command line program pdftk was dropped. I use pdftk every day, so I am working on using this PDFTK fork https://gitlab.com/marcvinyals/pdftk from the instructions found at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028522/how-can-i-install-pdftk-in-ubuntu-18-04-bioni

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar pdftk.jar
```

Now I have built the bash script named pdftk with the code above and placed it in `/usr/local/bin/` and made it executable with

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/pdftk
```

I have copied the `pdftk.jar` file to `/usr/local/bin/` and made it executable with the same command.

Not working as I hoped right now:

```
me@mine:~/M$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/pdftk
    ---xr-xr-x 1 root root 32 May  3 13:38 /usr/local/bin/pdftk

me@mine:~/M$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/pdftk.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 742367 May  2 16:32 /usr/local/bin/pdftk.jar
```

When I try to make it work in any directory it fails.

```
me@mine:~/M$ pdftk *.pdf output john.pdf
    Error: Unable to access jarfile pdftk.jar
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well now it shows me the pdftk help file.

Comment: apologies, I forgot to add `"$@"` which passes the arguments (starting with `$1`) as quoted arguments to `java` invocation. So you received the help output because the arguments you gave to the shell script weren't passed on. I corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `pdftk.jar` and your `pdftk` shell script live side by side inside `/usr/local/bin` all that should be necessary is to pass the actual path to the JAR file. You can either do that in the shell script thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -jar /usr/local/bin/pdftk.jar "$@"
```

or, in my opinion the more robust solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -jar "$0.jar" "$@"
```

The latter uses the name of the shell script and appends the `.jar` suffix. That's all it really does. So as long as they both live in the same directory, this should work. Even if you move them around in tandem. Whereas the first solution would require that you adjust the shell script to use the new path to the JAR file.

I prefer to give the double quotes also, because if *you* ever decide to copy the two files into a path with a blank space in it, the script would break.

I also changed the hashbang as this one is more portable (across various Linux and BSD flavors).

Comment: Maybe a better idea would be to stick the jar file under `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @jpaugh yeah, debatable. But that would complicate the shell script a bit. Then it should be executing `java -jar "${0//\/bin\//\/lib\/}.jar"` (if you're not familiar with string substitutions in Bash that's quite a mouthful to chew on) ... provided that the only difference in the path is `/bin/` versus `/lib/`.

Comment: me@mine:~/Desktop$ /usr/local/bin/pdftk *.pdf output bob.pdf
SYNOPSIS
       pdftk <input PDF files | - | PROMPT>
      [ input_pw <input PDF owner passwords | PROMPT> ]
      [ <operation> <operation arguments> ]
       For Complete Help: pdftk --help

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thank you. Works Perfect now with the second quote. java -jar "$0.jar" "$@"